# Process taking up high CPU

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I have a mixed mode C++ .exe running as a service in a Windows Server 2012 machine. This process continuously takes up more than 50% of the total CPU of the machine (2 cores). However, if I run the service in Windows 7, it takes only about 5-10% CPU.

The culprit thread's stack (taken from Process Explorer) is as below:

```
ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x2246
ntoskrnl.exe!ExAcquireCacheAwarePushLockExclusive+0x51a
ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x5f12
ntoskrnl.exe!KeIsAttachedProcess+0x8ba
ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x4133
mscorlib.ni.dll+0x4052a4
mscorlib.ni.dll+0x3c20
clr.dll!DllCanUnloadNowInternal+0xfb91
clr.dll!DllUnregisterServerInternal+0x9630
KERNEL32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x8f
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x5a
```

What is this thread about? And what is the reason for this high CPU usage? How should I go about debugging and solving this issue?

Comment: How many cores does the Windows 7 machine have?  A new desktop machine may have up to 8 cores meaning the CPU usage is about correct. (For the pedants out there you can buy machines with more than 8 cores but they are verging on ridiculous money.)

Comment: Is this a custom service you have written?  What does it do?

Comment: @wallyk yea it's a custom service. Just doing some convoluted file I/O and network stuff. I inherited the service.

Comment: You may want to post the important part of the code so it would be possible to analyze where the high load comes from. Do you have a loop which is busy-waiting? Introducing a small sleep of 1 ms would help then. Besides, I think graham.reeds had a good idea about what causes the smaller load on your second machine, since apparently your app uses only one core.

Comment: @graham.reeds  the Windows 7 machine is single core. Btw, the stack trace doesn't have any of "my" code. It's all ntdll, kernel32, clr, mscorelib, and ntoskernerl dlls

Comment: Single core?! How old is this machine?

Comment: Very. But no problem there.

Comment: Show the code that calls `RtlInitializeExceptionChain`, particularly the parameter values.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6852839/886887) suggests that the difference might be that the Windows 7 install is 32-bit, matching the application.  If you are able to rebuild your application as 64-bit, perhaps it will run better on the server.

Comment: I've run into a very similar issue. Where you able to find a resolution to this problem?