# Troubleshooting Orphaned DataSnap Thread

Tags: delphi, indy, datasnap, orphan-process

## Background Information

I have a `DataSnap` service that allows TCP connections from clients, and uses two filters, 1) compression, and 2) PC1 encryption.  The service has an array of database connections, which allows users to connect to one of 100+ databases.

The client is a Windows 32bit application.  When a user connects, the service determines their database and uses a connection from the array to connect them to their database.  All users who use the same database use the same db connection in the array.

When a users disconnect, the `DataSnap` service decrements a counter so it knows when the last user disconnects from a given database.  When the counter hits zero, the service closes the `TSQLConnection` to the database.  The `TSQLConnection` has auto-clone enabled so many users can query/post data without waiting for each other (besides normal database transactions).

## Issue

When a user disconnects, it appears that most time, all of their threads in the `DataSnap` service are freed, but not always.

Over time, orphaned threads in the `DataSnap` service continuously use more and more CPU.  If you look at the **Threads** in *Process Explorer*, you will see hundreds of threads that use about 2 million cycles/second (~0.008% of the overall CPU per thread), even when **no** users are connected.  In just 2 weeks, 200 threads will be orphaned, which results in ~0.7 trillion cycles/second (~7% of continuous CPU utilization).  By 4 weeks, those numbers are doubled.  The ONLY thing that fixes it is to restart the service.

This is the stack trace from an orphaned thread (captured with *Process Explorer*):

> ntoskrnl.exe!KiCpuId+0xaa
>   wow64cpu.dll!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x6c0
>   wow64cpu.dll!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x4a8
>   wow64.dll!Wow64SystemServiceEx+0x1ce
>   wow64.dll!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x42a ntdll.dll!longjmp+0x2cbe4
>   ntdll.dll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe ntdll.dll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x15
>   mswsock.dll+0x6d20 ws2_32.dll!select+0x9f
>   IndySystem260.bpl!@Idstackwindows@TIdSocketListWindows@FDSelect$qqrp17Idwinsock2@TFDSett1t1xi+0x4c
>   IndySystem260.bpl!@Idstackwindows@TIdSocketListWindows@SelectRead$qqrxi+0x25
>   IndyCore260.bpl!@Idsockethandle@TIdSocketHandle@Readable$qqri+0x71
>   IndyCore260.bpl!@Idiohandlerstack@TIdIOHandlerStack@Readable$qqri+0xb
>   IndyCore260.bpl!@Idiohandler@TIdIOHandler@CheckForDataOnSource$qqri+0x39
>   IndyCore260.bpl!@Idcustomtcpserver@TIdCustomTCPServer@DoExecute$qqrp20Idcontext@TIdContext+0x1e
>   rtl260.bpl!@System@Classes@CheckSynchronize$qqri+0x2a4
>   rtl260.bpl!@System@@Assert$qqrx20System@UnicodeStringt1i+0x66
>   ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63
>   ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36

## Question

Does anyone have a suggestion about how to troubleshoot why `rtl260.bpl` is stuck in a `CheckSynchronize()` loop, and what **Indy** is doing?  Or has anyone else seen this issue before, and how did you solve it?

Does `RtlInitializeExceptionChain()` mean an exception was thrown, or is that just part of Delphi's normal exception handling setup?

Comment: `RtlInitializeExceptionChain()` is an internal Windows function used to initialize exception handling ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6852895/12763954)).

Comment: It seems like Indy is blocked when calling the Winsock [`select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select) function. If the `timeout` parameter is set to null, it can wait forever.

Comment: Does your client close connections properly?

Comment: Yes, and most of the time all server resources are freed.

Comment: Interesting comment about the `select()` function.  I'll look into that...  Thank you.

Comment: I just read a post by Remy Lebeau where he said Indy uses blocking sockets, which must timeout before they invalidate and close the socket.  I don't think there is a way to make an orphaned blocked socket communicate with the client endpoint, to make it realize the connection has been lost and therefore invalidate and close itself.

Comment: As a workaround, you could schedule an automatic reboot of the server once per week.

Comment: I might schedule a service restart each weekend -- thanks for the idea.  Although, I would prefer for it to just run forever without requiring a restart -- like most Linux servers...  As long as I'm tied to Windows, periodic server reboots and service restarts are unfortunately inevitable...